# I can't access my api of the another domain

Tags: javascript, java, cors, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm making a java API REST and a front-end application with pure JS(yes, no framework), when I access by same domain, my application works perfectly, but when I try access by another domain I can't.

My filter in java application is like this:

```
after((req, resp) -> {
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,DELETE,POST,OPTIONS");
        resp.header("Content-Encondig", "gzip");
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.type("application/json");
    });
```

And my JS request is like this:

```
static get(startDate,endDate){
    return fetch(`http://localhost:4567/api/schedule/${startDate}/${endDate}`,{
        mode : "cors",
    })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .catch(error => erroe)
}
```

**Important:** if I access by another domain, but directly on browser, I get the JSON perfectly
**Backend :** [java Spark frameWork](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#stopping-the-server)

Comment: What errors do you get where? What happens on the Spark end? Are you logging the requests? Which ones come in? Take a look at [ask]. This might also make more sense as a before filter.

Comment: You could also just implement what they do in their own tutorial. https://sparktutorials.github.io/2016/05/01/cors.html (although the before filter works just as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, in my application JS I called the request for http://localhost:4567/api, then when I was access  the application by other domain, the application call the request for self, so the solution was change localhost by application ip address.